# How can a constant be defined for use with webkitTransition?

Tags: javascript

How can the following be rewritten to use a variable:

```
element.style.webkitTransition = "opacity 1.0s ease";
```

I tried these but none of them work:

```
var kDuration = 1.0;
element.style.webkitTransition = "opacity kDurations ease";

var kDuration = 1.0;
element.style.webkitTransition = "opacity kDuration ease";

var kDuration = 1.0;
element.style.webkitTransition = "opacity kDuration s ease";

var kDuration = 1.0;
element.style.webkitTransition = "opacity kDuration + s ease";

var kDuration = 1.0s;
element.style.webkitTransition = "opacity kDuration ease";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var kDurationfirst = "1.0s"; var kDuration= "opacity "+kDurationfirst +" ease";
element.style.webkitTransition = kDuration ;
```

Comment: If I use this then the animation stops working, it works if I revert back to "opacity 1.0s ease"